# HexString to Base64 to PDF not working for Internet Explorer (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, base64

I've got an application which converts a hexstring to base64, which will be converted to different mime-types.

It works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work with Internet Explorer.

Could you show me, what I'm doing wrong?

```
hexToBase64: function (hexstring) {
            return btoa(hexstring.match(/\w{2}/g).map(function (a) {
                return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(a, 16));
            }).join(""));
        }




hexToPDF: function (str) {
            var b64 = this.hexToBase64(str);

            var pdfWindow = window.open("");
            pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(b64) + "'></iframe>");

        }
```

I think it has to do something with the Iframe, but I'm not sure what else to use for internet explorer.

Comment: Sounds more like IE can't **display** a pdf in a webpage.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense!

How would I change it, to download it instead?

Comment: You can try to identify the IE browser using your JS code and try to download the file if browser is IE other wise you can display the PDF content.